# Hyperlink formatting mistakenly changes code

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, editor

I posted a code example in C with square brackets and ones (accessing element at indexes `1, 1` in a 2D array; here is a link to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30411692/335858)). Once I pasted a link using the bar button, however, my code example got changed (here is a [link to the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30411692/1)). There were two additional URLs number 2 and 3, pointing to the link of my first example. I caught that, and removed these two URLs, but I missed the changes made to my code.

To fix this bug, the code that renumbers URLs should ignore everything formatted as code.

The bug is easy to reproduce:

- In a new answer window type and highlight a word "Link"
- Highlight the word "Link", and click the [link] button in the tool bar
- In the dialog that opens type `http://www.google.com`; close the dialog
- Your screen should look like this:[image: first link]
- In the space between the link and the list of URLs type a code example that looks like this: `int a[1][1];`. Indent by four spaces to format it as code
- Type another word "Link" under your code.
- Highlight the second "Link", and click the [link] button in the tool bar
- In the dialog that opens type `http://www.yahoo.com`; close the dialog
- Now your screen should look like this:[image: second link]

Note how the code got changed from `a[1][1]` to `a[1][2]`, and an extra URL at number 2 got added to the list.

Comment: Simple:  Don't use the button to insert links :-) (Yes, I agree with you, needs to be fixed.)

Comment: @JonasCz: Well, for pictures you are just about stuck with them, if you want to upload them automatically.

Comment: I think there is also an issue when adding an image to a post that already has numbered links.

Comment: @Deduplicator, If it affects pictures too, then I agree, it's really a problem.

Comment: Note that the bug is also present when using the keyboard shortcut (`ctrl L`) to insert the links.

Comment: I believe this is well-known. There should be an already opened question on meta so or meta se.

Comment: I've met this before http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276293/960757. And it's really a kind of thing that might seriously break your answer. @Brock, it happens only if you use that link dialog.

Comment: Even simpler, don't use multidimensional arrays [:D](http://m.99wallpaper.com/images/7_1876/Troll-face-001.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build; for details see [my answer on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154936/adding-a-new-link-to-a-post-messes-up-indexes-in-square-brackets-in-code-already/258846#258846).